# Program to show a number appears (N/2 + 1) times

Tags: c

I'm a beginner at programming. I wrote a program to show that a number appears (N/2 + 1) times. But every time I run it, my cmd crashes. I am thinking maybe I have an error with my array.

My text file - `values3.txt` has the numbers `{2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1}`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define range_of_nums 3

int main(void)
{   
    int i;
    int num_of_values = 8;
    int a[num_of_values];
    int freq[range_of_nums];
    int current = 0;
    int found_number = 0;

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("values3.txt", "r");

    for (i=0;i<num_of_values;i++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    for (i=0;i<num_of_values;i++)
    {
        current = a[i] - 1;
        freq[current] += 1;
    }

    num_of_values = num_of_values / 2;

    for(i=0;i<range_of_nums;i++)
    {
        if (freq[i] > num_of_values)
        {
            found_number = i+1;
        }
    }

    if (found_number != 0)
    {
        printf("The number %d occurs more than N/2 %d times \n", found_number, num_of_values);
    }

    else 
    {
        printf("No number occurs more than N/2 times\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Possible** (not a c guy) hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414215/initial-value-of-int-array-in-c (freq)

Comment: How exactly is the text file? Does it have the `{`, `,`, etc as well?

Comment: "my cmd crashes", cmd.exe from windows crash or **your** program crash ?

Comment: @Stargateur Sorry, my program crashes*

Comment: @J...S it's one number per line. 
2
3
2
2
2
3
2
1

Comment: You also need to initialize the values in `freq` to 0.  As it is, they could initially contain any value.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually on the right path, you just fell off by failing to validate your file was open and in your loop logic at the end. You also have a problem in not validating that you actually got `num_of_values` values from your file.

Let's start by eliminating the "Where is the `values3.txt` file?" problem. `main()` provides the ability for your to pass arguments in, such as a filename, make use of that. The declaration for `main` accepting arguments is:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])  /* where argc arguments are passed in argv */
```

This eliminates the hardcoding of `values3.txt` in your program. Just pass the filename as the first argument and

```
FILE *fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");
```

Or, take it one better and use a *ternary* operator to open the file in `argv[1]` if it is given, otherwise read from `stdin` (by default):

```
FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
```

Always validate your file is open for reading, and handle the error if it is not, e.g.

```
if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
    fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
```

Another significant issue you had was failure to initialize `freq` to zero. When you start `freq[current] += 1;` in your code, `freq[current]` must have been set to zero beforehand to make that make any sense. A simple initialization is all you need:

```
    freq[range_of_nums] = {0},      /* you must initialize freq */
```

On to the logic issues. You want to read up to a *maximum* of `num_of_values` integer values into `a`, but no more. Reading even 1 more would invoke *Undefined Behavior*. There is no guarantee that there will always be `8` integers in the file. What if there were `6`? What if there were `26`? You must handle all cases. So instead of using a `for (i = 0; i < num_of_values; i++)` loop why not just read all the value and make sure you don't read more than `num_of_values`? Something like:

```
/* read each value up to num_of_values */
while (i < num_of_values && fscanf (fp, "%d", &a[i]) == 1)
    i++;
```

How could you adjust if you only read `6` values? Maybe:

```
if (i != num_of_values)             /* validate 8 values read */
    num_of_values = i;              /* if not adjust number   */
```

(**note:** you already know it cannot be more from your test in front of `fscanf`)

You don't necessarily want to alter your variable holding the number of elements in your array (that's kinda important to keep around). Why don't we use a new variable to hold `N/2` (say `num_by_2`. Then you could do:

```
num_by_2 = num_of_values / 2;       /* you need another var */
```

while still preserving `num_of_values` for use later in your code.

Lastly, if I understand correctly, you want to identify all numbers that appear more than `N/2` time. You have a logic problem in your loop layout. To find all values that appear greater than `N/2` times, the `printf` needs to be in that loop, e.g.

```
for (i = 0; i < range_of_nums; i++)
{
    if (freq[i] > num_by_2)
    {
        found_number = i + 1;
        printf ("The number %d occurs more than N/2 %d times \n",
                found_number, num_by_2);
    }
}
```

Now you know if `found_number` has a value, a value was found. So your last test could simply be:

```
if (found_number == 0) 
    printf("No number occurs more than N/2 times\n");
```

Putting it altogether, you could clean the logic up with something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define range_of_nums 3

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{   
    int i = 0,
        num_of_values = 8,              /* you have 8 values */
        a[num_of_values],               /* otherwise your VLA is wrong */
        freq[range_of_nums] = {0},      /* you must initialize freq */
        num_by_2 = 0,
        found_number = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each value up to num_of_values */
    while (i < num_of_values && fscanf (fp, "%d", &a[i]) == 1)
        i++;

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);       /* close file if not stdin */

    if (i != num_of_values)             /* validate 8 values read */
        num_of_values = i;              /* if not adjust number   */

    for (i = 0; i < num_of_values; i++) /* set frequency array vals */
        freq[a[i] - 1] += 1;

    num_by_2 = num_of_values / 2;       /* you need another var */

    for (i = 0; i < range_of_nums; i++)
    {
        if (freq[i] > num_by_2)
        {
            found_number = i + 1;
            printf ("The number %d occurs more than N/2 %d times \n",
                    found_number, num_by_2);
        }
    }

    if (found_number == 0) 
        printf("No number occurs more than N/2 times\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "2 3 2 2 2 3 2 1" | ./bin/numby2freq
The number 2 occurs more than N/2 4 times
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

This list of bugs can be non complete.

```
fp = fopen("values3.txt", "r");
```

You don't look if your file has been open

```
fp = fopen("values3.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
  perror("fopen()");
  return 1;
}
```

---

```
fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[i]);
```

You don't verify if fscanf sucess

```
int ret = fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[i]);
if (ret != 1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "error input");
  return 1;
}
```

---

```
current = a[i] - 1;
freq[current] += 1;
```

You trust user input, index could be out of range

```
current = a[i] - 1;
if (current < 0 || curent >= 8) {
  fprintf(stderr, "error range");
  return 1;
}
freq[current] += 1;
```

Comment: I implemented your code and it says no such file or directory

Comment: @Brady So what is your conclusion ?