# How to initialize empty 2d array in Arduino with default 0 values?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, arduino

I want to initialize 2d array with default 0 values.
`rows` and `columns` are dynamically changed values

```
int data[rows][columns] = { {}, {} };
```

And getting error

```
error: variable-sized object 'data' may not be initialized
   int data[rows][columns] = { {}, {} };
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [variable-sized object may not be initialized c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751075/variable-sized-object-may-not-be-initialized-c)

Comment: the problem is that your compiler does not know the values of rows and columns at compile-time. please note that dynamic memory allocation usually is not a good idea in MCUs, so you should have very good reasons to do that. I'm quite surprised that an experienced developer and SO member like you can't google error messages. ;)

Comment: @Piglet , it is also possible that before there are `#define rows (6)` or something like that. The pre-processor will substitute `rows` with a number. We just do not know the code before. (however, it is just an hypothesis)

Comment: Very bad idea when you have only a few bytes of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ''= { {}, {} }''

Since you can't add an entire array later down the sketch, I assume you insert it per row and per colum into the array.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, and as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56871827/initial-value-of-int-array-in-c-why), If you do NOT use dynamic allocation (for example `malloc`), the values are automatically initialized to `0`.
So, simply:

```
#define rows (3)
#define columns (4)

//...

int data[rows][columns];

//...

int main(){ 
    //...
}
```

**Please note** that the value of `rows` and `columns` must be known at compile-time.

However, when you use `malloc`, you can iterate on the indices:

```
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<columns;i++){
        data[i][j]=0;
    }
}
```